# How to program for loop so that it can stop on the Nth occurence of a condition?

Tags: python-3.x, excel, openpyxl

I am trying to transfer data from one worksheet to another using Openpyxl on python. My script works but it's not doing what i want it to do.  Based on the ID column, the data from 4th column from the original spreadsheet is transferred to the designated spreadsheet. I am having trouble dealing with duplicate IDs. How do I get the for loop to stop and append to a separate list at the first occurrence that it matches the "if" condition AND if there's a second occurrence, append that too and stop at the 2nd occurrence, and for a third occurrence, etc... The purpose of this is just so that it would copy and paste the correct data into the right cell on the 4th column based on the ID. Appreciate any insight at all. Thank you in advance!

Here are the links to the sample spreadsheets.

[Designated spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVx2r.png)
[Original Spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kiBn0.png)

> ```
> from openpyxl import load_workbook
> wb1 = load_workbook('GradeSample.xlsx')
> wb1_sheet1 = wb1["Sheet1"]
> wb2 = load_workbook('GradeSample1.xlsx')
> wb2_sheet1 = wb2["Sheet1"]
>
> rangeselected = []
>
> for i in range(2, 10, 1):
>     for j in range(2, 10, 1):
>         if wb1_sheet1.cell(row=i, column=1).value == wb2_sheet1.cell(row=j, column=1).value:
>             rangeselected.append(wb1_sheet1.cell(row=j, column=4).value)
>             continue
>             wb2_sheet1.cell(row=i, column=4).value = rangeselected[i - 2]
>         else:
>             rangeselected.append(0)
>
> wb2.save(filename="GradeSample1.xlsx")
> ```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you the result to look like and, hence, how the conditions should work.

Answer (score 0):

You could append the data to a list each time you add it to the excel file and you could have an if statement that checks if the data is in the list, and if it is then it appends to a new list.

```
    if [data var] in [list name]:
        [append to new excel file]
```

Before this of course you would need to be adding all the data to a separate list.

I'm sure there are other ways to do it, this is just the first thing that comes to mind for me. Hope this makes sense/is helpful!

Answer (score 0):

```
for row in range(2,wb1_sheet1.max_row):
    if wb1_sheet1.cell(row=row, column=1).value == wb2_sheet1.cell(row=row, column=1).value:
        wb2_sheet1.cell(row=row, column=4).value = wb1_sheet1.cell(row=row, column=4).value
```

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.